# How to remove item from di.xml in magento2?

Tags: magento2, downloadable

```
<type name="Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="downloadablePanel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\DownloadablePanel</item>
            <item name="links" xsi:type="string">Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Links</item>
            <item name="samples" xsi:type="string">Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Samples</item>
            <item name="usedDefault" xsi:type="string">Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\UsedDefault</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

I want to remove below code from di.xml

```
    <item name="samples" xsi:type="string">Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Samples</item>
```

Can anyone help how to achieve this?

i want to remove below code from product edit page:
[image]

Comment: I have not tried this but can you try xsi:type="null". Reference taken from - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html

Comment: I have tried this already but not working

Comment: If it does not work, it will be great if you share your requirement more, that way may be someone can help you with an alternative.

Comment: @LAW i have added one image in question.please check if you can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know if you can remove something, but you can make it do nothing.

Create your own class that looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui;

class DummyProvider implements \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\ModifierInterface
{
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
         return $data;
    }
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
         return $meta;
    }
}
```

this class does nothing to the data or meta of the ui form.
Then replace what you want to remove with this class.
Add this in the `di.xml` of your module

```
<type name="Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="downloadablePanel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DummyProvider</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

This should cancel the effect of `Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Samples`.
I haven't tested the code though.

Comment: Yes it seems like the answer shared by sania and marius is the way out for this.

Comment: It does not seem to work for me. New modifier is added but not replacing the existing item. I got it to work just using `unset($meta['dowloadable']);` in modifyMeta but it does not seem as efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you want to change the links one.
You have to create your own module that depends on the Magento_Downloadable module and add this in the di.xml of your module.

```
<type name="Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="links" xsi:type="string">Your\ClassName\Goes\Here</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Just keep in mind that if the code you posted is from frontend/di.xml you have to add the new code in frontend/di.xml. Same goes for adminhtml/di.xml

Comment: Nope , i want to remove
i don't want to customize it

Comment: Yes it help me to reach at solution

Comment: most welcome glade to help you